# Выдает ошибку в s2 := s[1]; индекс вне границ массив и не возможно найти файл input.txt

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
function corrector (s:string):string;
var
  s2: string;
  o: byte;
  i, k: integer;
begin
  o := 1;
  repeat
    if copy(s, o, 2) = '  ' then
      s := copy(s, 1, o) + copy(s, o + 2, length(s))
    else
      o := o + 1
  until (o > length(s));
  s2 := s[1];
  for k := 2 to length(s) do
  begin
    if s[k - 1] <> s[k] then
      s2 := s2 + s[k];    
  end;
  for i := 1 to length(s2) do
    if (s2[i] in ['.', ',', ':', ';', '?']) then
    begin
      if (s2[i + 1] <> ' ') then
        insert(' ', s2, i + 1);
    end;
  corrector:=s2;
  end;
  var   f_in:text;
        f_out:text;
        s:string;
  begin
      AssignFile(f_in,'input.txt');
      reset(f_in);
      readln(f_in,s);
      close(f_in);
      s :=corrector(s);
      AssignFile(f_out,'output.txt');
      reset(f_out);
      writeln(f_out,s);
      close(f_out);
  end.
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: `copy(s, o, 2)` - может все-таки `0` вместо `o`?

Comment: Во-первых s непристойное значение никакое.
Во-вторых ошибка потому что вы в конце хочете визвать файл, зачем неизвестно. Какая суть задачи, что она должна делать? (Я понимаю ±как она работает, но что из этого должно получиться понять не удается).